# Regex only match specific whitespaces

Tags: regex, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have some javascript code that i would like to minify using regex.

My goal is to turn this:

```
function mFunct(variable){
var a, b, c;
new Class();
}
```

Into this:

```
function mFunct(variable){var a,b,c;new Class();}
```

I have tried this regular expression:

```
(?:(new|var|function)\s)|\s
```

but it selects `var a` from the javascript code, which contains a crucial whitespace.

How can I change the regular expression so that it doesn't select it?

Comment: What are you writing this in? Python? Java?

Comment: There is almost certainly a flavourless way to write this regex. The exact language should not necessarily matter.

Comment: Does this need to be done in regex, or is that just what you wanted to do it in?

Comment: I will just [leave this here...](https://github.com/Twoody/minifyPy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure matching only whitespace that is not preceeded by the keywords:

```
(?<!function|var|new)\s
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/mAOqOb/1). We can't see the newlines being highlighted, them having no width and all, but in the list on the right you see the characters being matched. Removing all those matched characters should give the desired output.